# How to create log file of my web site in php?

Tags: php, logging

I want to know how to create log file of my web site in php? Which help me to maintain data about Pages visited by each user & all actions they done in my website. So any buddy can help me?

Thanx,

Comment: what you need to register in your log?

Comment: What information you want to store? Pages visited by each user, general actions... please be more clear!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$file = 'people.log';
// The new person to add to the file
$person = "John Smith\n";
// Write the contents to the file, 
// using the FILE_APPEND flag to append the content to the end of the file
// and the LOCK_EX flag to prevent anyone else writing to the file at the same time
file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Please see the manual page for [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

Comment: Thanks for improving this answer. I have removed my downvote.