# Javascript serverside logging of method times

Tags: php, javascript, logging, server-side

I just got an internship at a webdev shop and my first job is to solve a problem one of our clients is having.  Long story short there is some problem in some code written by a former employee, and loading times are being slowed on the client's website for some unknown reason.  My boss has told me to insert a logger into the code so I can record the amount of time a given method takes, and find which method is "hogging" the time.  I have to print a log of time taken for a given method to a log file on the SERVER.  For example I want to do something like this:

```
function search(x,acc)
    {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
            //
            //
            //method code
            //
            //
            var timeTaken = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
            //the question is now how do I print that to some kind of 
            //server side log file i.e.  "/etc/etc/logFile.log"
    }
```

I'm a bit confused about this because obviously Javascript is interpretted clientside and I want this file to exist server side, and I'm not sure where to start with this.  For reference the pages are .php files with the js embedded in HTML.

Edit:  I've attempted something here with the help of some of the answers.  Lets see how good/bad this solution is.

```
 //js function:
 function search(x,acc)
    {
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        //do some stuff
        var middleOfFunction = new Date().getTime() - startTime;
        // do some more stuff
        var endOfFunction = new Date().getTime() - middleOfFunction;
        //find out which chunk of code took longer, the beginning or the end

    var max = Math.max(endOfFunction , middleOfFunction);

        <?php 
            $message = 'The longest part of the function took :' . $max . ' seconds.'
            file_put_contents($file, $message , FILE_APPEND |     LOCK_EX);
        ?>
```

The actual code is a bit more complex than this, I have a more descriptive message that shows what part of the code took longer, but this is the basic idea.  Does this make sense, or will the php be ran serverside before any of the JS gets ran clientside?  I'm confused about this sort of stuff.  Thanks to everyone for your help, it means a lot to me.  I'm trying to show up to my second day of work having worked from home a lot, so I dont have my boss around to ask him questions.

Thanks again,
Break.

Comment: who got this job you or us?

Comment: I'm not asking for you to give me any code, just a pointer to some reference material involving this sort of thing.  I'm new to javascript and could really use a push in the right direction.  I respect your apprehension though.

Comment: I would log it client side via firebug(or alternative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best idea is with AJAX/$.post();

Everytime something happens, you do:

```
$.post("url/to/php_file.php",{variable: "its_content"},function(response){
  if(response=="what_you_wanted_to_happen")
    alert(response_or_some_other_variable);//or do nothing, but for debugg do some alerts
  else
     //do something else here
});
```

On server side you can find info here: [How to create log file of my web site in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400347/how-to-create-log-file-of-my-web-site-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try microtime(true);

```
$start = microtime(true);
// do stuff
$totaltime = microtime(true) = $start;
```

and to log:

```
file_put_contents($file, $totaltime, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: exactly my thoughts, I could insert this code with a php tag at the beginning and end of each js code block I'd like to time... but I believe the php will be ran serverside before the client executes any of the JS, right?

Answer (score 0):

You could store in a `"<input type='hidden' name='jsTime' id='jsTime' />`. Your JavaScript might look like:

```
function E(e){
  return document.getElementById(e);
}
function timeTaken(hiddenId, submitId, func, funcArgsArray){
  E(submitId).onclick = function(){
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    func.apply(func, funcArgsArray);
    E(hiddenId).value = new Date().getTime() - start;
  }
}
```

If you had `<input type='submit' name='sub' id='sub' value='SUBMIT' />`, and the hidden input above, and a function called `testFunction`, with two arguments, then you would use this function like:

```
timeTaken('jsTime', 'sub', testFunction, ['arg1', variable2]);
```

Since `onclick` fires before submission, the hidden value will be updated, so the Server can access it with `$_GET['jsTime']` or `$_POST['jsTime']`.

Note: this would only test a JavaScript function time.